# What does it mean to normalize a combination of Spherical Harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, spherical-harmonics

Using the following as an example:

> Show that the combinations $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y_{11}-Y_{1-1}\right)\quad\text{&}\quad\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y_{11}+Y_{1-1}\right)$$ are real and normalized.
>
> Where $$Y_{1\pm 1}=\mp\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta e^{\pm i\phi}$$

---

So for the first combination we have $$\begin{align}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y_{11}-Y_{1-1}\right)&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \,e^{i\phi}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \,e^{-i\phi}\right]\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)\right]\\&=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\&=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\frac{x}{r}\end{align}$$

where in the last step I used the fact that $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$ in spherical polar coordinates.

---

For the second combination

$$\begin{align}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y_{11}+Y_{1-1}\right)&=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left[-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \,e^{i\phi}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \,e^{-i\phi}\right]\\&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\theta \left(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}\right)\right]\\&=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\sin\theta\sin\phi\\&=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\frac{y}{r}\end{align}$$

where in the last step I used the fact that $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ in spherical polar coordinates.

---

The calculation is obviously not the problem here. It is the meaning of the result that concerns me. The author of this question mentions in the solution that:

> They are obviously real. The spherical harmonics are orthogonal and normalized, $\color{blue}{\text{so the square integral of the two new functions will just give }}\color{blue}{\frac12(1+1)=1}$.

I know that the word 'normalize' is quite ubiquitous as it seems to have different meanings depending on the context.

For example:

> The wavefunction for a particle confined to $0\le x \le a$ in the ground state is $$\Psi(x)=A\sin\left(\frac{\pi\, x}{a}\right)$$ where $A$ is the normalization constant. Find $A$ and hence the normalized wavefunction $\psi(x)$.

---

> Omitting all calculations using the '*Normalization Condition*':
>
> $$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}{\big|\Psi(x)\big|}^2\,dx=1\tag{1}$$
>
> The **Normalized wavefunction** is $$\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi\,x}{a}\right)$$

The words "Normalized wavefunction" make perfect sense to me as it has been normalized such that the condition $(1)$ is satisfied.

---

But what does it mean to say that $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y_{11}-Y_{1-1}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi}}\frac{x}{r}$$ is normalized?

Or put in another way; Where is the '*Normalization Condition*' for this?

At a guess, I think the answer lies somewhere in what the Professor wrote in the quote above which I have marked blue. But I don't fully understand the logic behind what the professor is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Orthogonality_and_normalization) choices for the normalization of spherical harmonics, but in your case it seems to be that $Y_{l,m} (\theta,\phi)$ is normalized if

$$
\int_0^\pi \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \sin(\theta)  \left|Y_{l,m} (\theta,\phi) \right|^2 = 1
$$

In problems like these it is often much easier to use the orthonormality of the spherical harmonic functions,

$$
\int_0^\pi \mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi \sin(\theta)  Y_{l,m} (\theta,\phi) Y_{l',m'}^{*} (\theta,\phi) = \delta_{l,l'}\delta_{m,m'}
$$

to test whether linear combinations of spherical harmonic functions are normalized.